# Count occurrence of words and only 1 in the same phrases

Tags: php

I have a problem where I need to count the number of times a word occurs in a given array.

I want the code to increase the count of a word (`'instagrammm'`) by 1 if the word is in the same phrases.

Here is my code:

```
$output = array();
$buzzes = ['instagramm some text instagramm', 'instagramm some text' , 'instagramm some text' , 'instagramm some text'];
foreach ($buzzes as $buzz) {
    $flag = 0;
    $words = explode(" ",$buzz);
    foreach ($words as $word)
    {
        $word = mb_convert_case($word, MB_CASE_LOWER, "UTF-8");
        $word = preg_replace('/^[^A-Za-z0-9\-]|[^A-Za-z0-9\-]$/', '', $word);

        if(strlen($word) > 2){
            if (array_key_exists($word, $output)){
                    $output[$word]++;
            }else{
                $output[$word] = 1;
            }    
        } 
    }
}
```

Here is the expected result:

```
Array
(
    [instagramm] => 4
    [some] => 4
    [text] => 4
)
```

Comment: What does "in the same phrases" mean? Could you provide examples that return nothing? (We can get a better idea of the program's expected behavior.)

Comment: Also, why do you want `instagrammm` to return 4 times, when it is present 5 times? Do you only want to count whether it is present (1+ times) or not in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems you are suppose to have another condition in your piece of code.
just modified your code with a condition.

```
 $output = array();
        $buzzes = array('instagramm some text instagramm', 'instagramm some text' , 'instagramm some text' , 'instagramm some text');
        foreach ($buzzes as $buzz) {
            $flag = 0;
            $words = explode(" ",$buzz);
            $wordArr    = array();
            foreach ($words as $word)
            {
                $word = mb_convert_case($word, MB_CASE_LOWER, "UTF-8");
                $word = preg_replace('/^[^A-Za-z0-9\-]|[^A-Za-z0-9\-]$/', '', $word);
                if(!in_array(strtolower($word),$wordArr)) {
                    if(strlen($word) > 2){
                        if (array_key_exists($word, $output)){
                                $output[$word]++;
                        }else{
                            $output[$word] = 1;
                        }    
                    }
                    $wordArr[]  = strtolower($word);
                }
            }
        }
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. It will be faster with fewer comparisons and allocations:

```
foreach ($buzzes as $buzz) {
    $words = array_unique(explode(' ',$buzz));
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        $word = mb_convert_case($word, MB_CASE_LOWER, "UTF-8");
        $word = preg_replace('/^[^A-Za-z0-9\-]|[^A-Za-z0-9\-]$/', '', $word);
        if(strlen($word) > 2){
            if (array_key_exists($word, $output)){
                $output[$word]++;
            }else{
                $output[$word] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

take a look:

```
// My version
Took: 0.178099 
Array
(
    [instagramm] => 4
    [some] => 4
    [text] => 4
)

// accepted version
Took: 25.308847 
Array
(
    [instagramm] => 4
    [some] => 4
    [text] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
$output = array();
$buzzes = ['instagramm some text instagramm', 'instagramm some text' , 'instagramm some text' , 'instagramm some text'];

foreach( explode( ' ', implode( ' ', $buzzes ) ) as $word )
{
    $word = strtolower( trim( $word ) );

    if( !empty( $word ) )
    {
        if( isset( $output[ $word ] ) )
        {
            $output[ $word ]++;
        }
        else{ $output[ $word ] = 1; }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [instagramm] => 5
    [some] => 4
    [text] => 4
)
```

Comment: thx for your help by but i wanted 4 times on instagramm but nvm ameenulla0007 gave me the solution